# Matplotlib center/align ticks in imshow plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have been trying to center the x and y ticks of my `imshow` but without success.

The desired `yticks` should be: `[ 100,  200,  300,  400,  500,  600,  700,  800,  900, 1000]` and `xticks`: `[ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]` but **aligned/centered**. E.g. line 1 should have the 100 value exactly in the middle of the line space (middle of the yellow box/pixel).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(10,11)
plt.figure(dpi=130)
plt.imshow(X, cmap = 'jet', interpolation=None, extent=[5,55,1000,100], aspect='auto')
```

**Here, the values `5` does not appear at all in the `x axis`.**

[image]

**I have also tried the following, x axis if fine but not the y axis**

```
plt.figure(dpi=130)
X = np.random.rand(10,11)
plt.imshow(X, cmap = 'jet', interpolation=None, extent=[2.5,57.5,1000,100], aspect='auto')
ax = plt.gca()
xticks = cluster_space
yticks = space_segment
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
```

[image]

Comment: So you want your axis to range from 0 to 60, and from 50 to 1050, right? Did you try those values?

Comment: No. I want the axes to be in the range that I have mentioned in my OP. But I need the ticks(values) to be perfectly centered in each line. Take 100 as example. I need 100 value to appear in the middle of the yellow box/pixel.

Comment: That's contradictory. But check my answer and if this is not what you want, you can use to explain how it should look instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to have the pixels centered, you need to set the extent to range from the lowest pixel coordinate minus half the pixel width to the highest pixel coordinate plus half the pixel width.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(10,11)
plt.figure()

centers = [5,55,1000,100]
dx, = np.diff(centers[:2])/(X.shape[1]-1)
dy, = -np.diff(centers[2:])/(X.shape[0]-1)
extent = [centers[0]-dx/2, centers[1]+dx/2, centers[2]+dy/2, centers[3]-dy/2]
plt.imshow(X, cmap = 'jet', interpolation=None, extent=extent, aspect='auto')

plt.xticks(np.arange(centers[0], centers[1]+dx, dx))
plt.yticks(np.arange(centers[3], centers[2]+dy, dy))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need.